# Floating, scrolling element is changing scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHLHW/)

I have a page, broken up into 3 sections.  A header, a sidebar, and a content section.  I'm trying to get the sidebar to scroll with the page until it hits the top, then stick there until we scroll back down, at which point it sticks to the bottom of the header.  Relevant snippet:

```
var Sidebar = $("#Dock"), pos = Sidebar.offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log('pre ' + Sidebar.hasClass('fixed') + ' | ' + $(this).scrollTop() + ' | ' + (pos.top + 10));
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > (pos.top + 10) && Sidebar.hasClass('notFixed')) {
        Sidebar.removeClass('notFixed');
        Sidebar.addClass('fixed');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= (pos.top + 10) && Sidebar.hasClass('fixed')) {
        Sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
        Sidebar.addClass('notFixed');
    }
    console.log('pos ' + Sidebar.hasClass('fixed') + ' | ' + $(this).scrollTop() + ' | ' + (pos.top + 10));
});
```

So here's what actually happens: We scroll down, we remove the `notFixed` class from our floating element, give it the `fixed` class, and then immediately jump to `$(this).scrollTop() = 23`.  Finally, any built up scroll events resolve, moving from our last position, and resetting to 23.  On the Fiddle, instead of 23 it's 0.

Why is it jumping back, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WHLHW/4/

The reason it wasn't working is because you had `height: 1000px` on `#dock`, and no height for body. So because the page was the height of `#dock`, you couldn't scroll past `#dock`.

So I did the following and it works now.

```
#dock {
    height:300px;
}

body {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be the case.  Dropping sample text in another div produces the expected behavior as well.  What happened was my console opens along the bottom, and was artificially shrinking the page and creating scrollable space in the browser.  Thanks.